# Calculating the semi-major axis with one point, the eccentricity and the center.

Tags: geometry

Given is one "random" point on the ellipse, the eccentricity and the center of the ellipse. How can I calculate the semi-major axis?

I'm not very math-savvy, so I hope the problem is easy to solve. Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** In some cases the ellipse is rotated on the y-axis.

**Edit 2:** So thanks to Cadenza I can calculate the semi-major axis if the ellipse is in a 2D space but what can I do if the ellipse is in a 3D space and rotated on the y-axis?

On a german Q&A website somebody said that it's impossible with these given informations. Is that true? If yes which informations except the semi-minor axis could be helpful?

Comment: Are you given any further information?  In some elementary exercises, it is assumed that the axes of the ellipse are horizontal and vertical in the $(x,y)$-plane rather than slanted.  I don't think there's enough in what you've posted to answer the question without either that or some other additional information.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry, I just realized that there could be cases where the ellipse is slanted(z-Axis).

Comment: @MichaelHardy With that I mean a rotation on the Y-Axis.

Comment: The answer you got clearly shows that you can get an ellipse satisfying the above contitions for any orientation of the axes. Just substitute $x$ and $y$ in that formula with the projections of the given point on the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Any "random" (a better word in this case is *arbitrary*) point $(x,y)$ on an ellipse whose axes are parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axes satisfy the equation

$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} = 1$$

where $(h,k)$ denotes the center of an ellipse, and $a$ and $b$ denote the semi-major and semi-minor axes ($a$ is semi-major if the ellipse is horizontal).

The *eccentricity* of an ellipse the ratio of $c$ to the semi-major axis (so if the ellipse is horizontal, the eccentricity is $\frac{c}{a}$). Here, $c$ is the focus of the radius, given by $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$ (again, horizontal case).

You are given $(x,y)$, $(h,k)$, and $\frac{c}{a}$ (or $\frac{c}{b}$). Can you use these equations to recover $a$ (or $b$)?

Note that there is also the case in which the ellipse is rotated (with respect to the standard axes), in which case you would have to consider a more complicated equation (see: [Rotation of axes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes)).

Comment: Your first sentence is not true.  An ellipse in the $(x,y)$-plane satisfies that equation if its axes are parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axes, but not if they are not.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for catching that. I was jumping too quick with my assumptions of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help in most cases.